# How to stub npm package `phin` with Sinon

Tags: javascript, sinon

I am trying to stub npm package `phin` but not having much luck. Any suggestions please?

Below is a simplied version of the code.

requestHelper.js

```
const phin = require('phin');

async function request(req) {
    return await phin(req);
}

module.exports = {request}
```

requestHelper.test.js

```
const requestHelper = require('./requestHelper.js');
const phin = require('./node_modules/phin');

sinon.stub(phin.prototype, 'constructor').returns(true);

const result = await requestHelper.request({"something":"something"})
expect(result).to.eql(true);
```

`sinon.stub(phin.prototype, 'constructor').returns(true)` =>

> Error: Trying to stub property 'constructor' of undefined

Comment: Is the syntax error in the JavaScript you posted a copy/paste issue?

Comment: @CarlMarkham yes a copy/paste issue; I've fixed that now. I still get the same error when I use `sinon.stub(phin.prototype, 'constructor').returns(true)` => `Error: Trying to stub property 'constructor' of undefined`

Comment: I could use `rewire` but I am trying to avoid introducing another module if I can avoid it.

    `const requestHelper = rewire('./requestHelper.js');`
    `requestHelper.__set__('phin', sinon.stub().returns(true));`

Answer (score 1):

Since sinon does not support stub standalone function import from a module, [Possible to stub a standalone utility function?](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/562). You can use [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) to do this.

Besides, I create a demo without installing the `phin` package, so I disabled *callThru* for `proxyquire`.

> If *callThru* is disabled, you can stub out modules that don't even exist on the machine that your tests are running on

`requestHelper.js`:

```js
const phin = require('phin');

async function request(req) {
  return await phin(req);
}

module.exports = { request };
```

`requestHelper.test.js`:

```js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire').noCallThru();
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('69852777', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const phinStub = sinon.stub().resolves(true);
    const requestHelper = proxyquire('./requestHelper', {
      phin: phinStub,
    });
    const result = await requestHelper.request({ something: 'something' });
    sinon.assert.match(result, true);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(phinStub, { something: 'something' });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  69852777
    ✓ should pass (1581ms)


  1 passing (2s)

------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File              | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files         |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 requestHelper.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```